# local_frame attribute returns none after vehicle is armed (ardurover-sitl)

Tags: dronekit-python, dronekit

I'm using python-droneKit along with dronekit-sitl / rover-2.50, and when I try to acquire the vehicle.location.local_frame NED coordinates (after the vehicle has been armed) I only get None values. 
I'd appreciate if you could help me in this matter, thanks.

Comment: It works on the sitl-copter though, is it possible that this attribute is not activated for the sitl-rover?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your parameter SR0_POSITION is higher than 0.

Comment: When I do " param show SR* " in mavproxy, it shows that parameter with a value of 4.0000.